# Are there any good practices to keep my Tor relay's private key safe?

Tags: relays, security, private-key

Assuming that I run a Tor relay on a virtual private server running linux, are there any good practices to keep my relay's private key safe?

We can take for granted that software packages constantly get updated and upgraded and that ssh access is restricted to ssh keys.

Should I use an encrypted loopback device to encrypt the private key? Are there any other attack vectors I should have in mind ?

Comment: This seems like it would be more useful on the Security SE site; it's not really specific to Tor (just the fact that his Linux server happens to be running a Tor relay).

Comment: Well one the one hand you're right, but there are Tor's specific security matters, such as how to protect your relay's private key.

Comment: If that's what's being asked, the qustion should be updated to reflect that. As is it's too broad and/or off topic (it sounds offtopic anyways).