# Hidden service private key chain

Tags: onion-services, security, private-key, certificate

Can a certificate chain be used for a hidden service's private key? It would be nice to be able to periodically re-sign a public key and upload it to the host. This would mean that in the case of the private key on the host being compromised, it is only valid for a short amount of time, due to the manual reauthorization process.

I'm not sure of the correct terminology to use, so I'll try to explain it with some examples and my reasoning behind wanting this:

- **Host:** I am `ONION_ADDRESS`, my public key is `HOST_PUBLIC_KEY`.
- **HSDir:** I don't trust that public key.
- **Host:** Here is the signature from root key `ROOT_PUBLIC_KEY`: `SIGNED_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY`.

Depending on whether the signature has expired:

- **HSDir:** `ROOT_PUBLIC_KEY` is valid, and that signature is valid. Go ahead.

or

- **HSDir:** `ROOT_PUBLIC_KEY` is valid, but that signature has expired. Goodbye.

The `ROOT_PRIVATE_KEY` is stored on a machine under physical control of the hidden service operator. The remote host is considered the weakest point. Should the remote host be compromised, all that can be obtained is `HOST_PRIVATE_KEY` (and of course `HOST_PUBLIC_KEY`), and the `SIGNED_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY`. Due to the signature being created with an expiry date, the adversary can only masquerade as the hidden service for as long as `SIGNED_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY` remains valid. Should the hidden service operator become aware of the host becoming compromised, he would not renew the signature. Once the `SIGNED_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY` expires, due to the absence of a renewed signature, `HOST_PUBLIC_KEY` will not be trusted, resulting in the adversary's loss of control of the hidden service.

The purpose of this is to limit the impact which a compromise would have. Further, once `SIGNED_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY` expires, the hidden service operator can regain exclusive control of the `.onion` address – it would not be necessary for a **new** `.onion` to be created.

Are there currently any methods (or any planned methods) which would allow for the host to be given partial/temporary authority to serve as the hidden service?

Related:

- [Protecting Hidden services .onion private key from your host](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/6060)
- [Are there any good practices to keep my Tor relay's private key safe?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/44)

Comment: This would be a pretty substantial redesign since the hidden service address is actually part of the main public key and there's nothing close to offering this kind of verification via the HSDir's. I see the value in compartmentalizing two separate services (and likely a good idea) but it's too far away from the current implementation to make any conclusions. It may be worth trying to integrate into the next version of hidden services.

Comment: Is this something you could just do for yourself using SSL certificates that expire, instead of your onion?